# Kivy Apk file from buildozer crashing

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I created an Apk file using buildozer, 
when I use anything from KivyMD 0.102.0 , the app does not launch on my honor play.
But when not using anything from KivyMD it works with same spec

File are in the gdrive folder

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1x3JKFGyMkk2aVzYpG6j31zmCa4T2CMKA

Comment: Please share the relevant part(s) of your code and let us know what error you receive or what result you see and what you expect.

Comment: Hi Arunav, I checked the folder which you have attached but the KivyMD folder is missing. Are you sure you built the apk along with the KivyMD folder ?

Comment: @normic I have added the code main.py and try.kv in the Google drive folder, the is in the question, I had no error while building, I have also tried other code ussing KivyMD, all are working on pc but not on phone, those without KivyMD are working fine... I used git clone for KivyMD

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh  I have KIVYMD folder, I have added the folder screenshot to the same drive folder.. Please take a look.. There are no errors

Comment: use logcat to see what are the errors on the android device when the apk runs on the phone. Go through the log and you'll see the errors. If you are unable to see the error, post the log here and one of us can have a look

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh. Sorry for the silly question.. but i am new to android and kivy, I had generated log when I build the apk and  it it in the drive, how can I generate it when the app runs on phone, any link

Comment: did you add git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git in the buildozer.spec file before cooking the apk ? ... KivyMD also has fonts so add ttf in the source.include_exts also

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh, yes I tried adding ttf it did not work. Where in the spec file should I add this git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh.. Thanks a lot ... The app was not able to link with kivymd folder.. The logcat was very useful.. Thank you for your guidance..

Comment: @Arunav: I didn't contribute to the topic itself, only tried to help you use SO.
To clean up everything and help others, just write an answer how you fixed it and after that accept your answer. Then everyone can see that this is solved and how.

Comment: @Arunav: Sounds great that you were able to resolve the issue. But having said that, as normic mentioned, do write an answer about how you were able to solve the issue. This would help the future budding developers with resolutions.  And for your previous question - the git+github.com..... goes in the requirements of buildozer.spec

Comment: @normic I have added an answer

Comment: @Chitkaran Singh. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

The application was crashing on android

On starting the application it showed kivy logo and then closed

I pulled out Logcat from my device using ADB. 
The issue is explained below-->

The application was not able to link to the 'kivymd' folder. There was an error in logcat saying that it was not able to find the 'kivymd. app', which is a python file in the kivymd folder.

Actually I did not include the 'kivymd' folder which had to pulled out of "KivyMD" folder that is created after cloning from  and running setup.py
On placing the kivymd folder in my project folder and cooking the apk, it worked

I also faced the same issue when I used "urllib" python library. It was fixed by exclusively adding it in 'requirements' of buildozer.spec file

So this basically happens when you don't include the libs. Required. 
It may also happen due version mismatch of python or kivy